# PHP case insensitive sort producing different results using the same data in different order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is extracted from a larger project I am working on, and the data set is not the same, but I have narrowed down the problem to as slim as possible, just declaring an array, sorting it and dumping it, yet the problem persists and is reproduceable.

This code:

```
<?php

$array = array("Z", "z", "Y", "y", "B", "b", "A", "a");

sort($array, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

var_dump($array);
```

Results in:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "y"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "Z"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "z"
}
```

But this code:

```
<?php

$array = array("Z", "z", "Y", "y", "b", "B", "a", "A");

sort($array, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

foreach( $array as $ar )
{
    echo $ar . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Results in:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "y"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "Z"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "z"
}
```

Why? It's the same data, in a different order, being sorted in the same way - surely it should produce the same consistent output?

I have spent days trying to figure this out and it is very frustrating. Maybe it is something simple, maybe not.

Comment: As you ignore case, they then become the same values and as the manual says *If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nigel's comment already explains the reason behind your inconsistent result, here's a workaround to obtain the required consistency.

```php
<?php
$array = array("Z", "z", "Y", "y", "B", "b", "A", "a");

sort($array, SORT_STRING);
sort($array, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

var_dump($array);

$array = array("Z", "z", "Y", "y", "b", "B", "a", "A");
sort($array, SORT_STRING);
sort($array, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

var_dump($array);
```